# How can I troubleshoot this install? Repeated errors when creating an environment from an .yml file

Tags: python, pip, conda, numba

I'm trying to install the behavior scoring software [A-SOiD](https://github.com/YttriLab/A-SOID/blob/main/README.md) on my macbook pro (OS: ventura 13.3.1 a). I've followed the instructions but have been unable to create the environment in conda from the .yml file.

I get the following errors:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: numba, llvmlite
  Building wheel for numba (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for numba (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for numba
  Building wheel for llvmlite (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for llvmlite (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for llvmlite
Failed to build numba llvmlite

Pip subprocess error:
WARNING: asoid 0.3 does not provide the extra 'dev'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/hf/67v6_61j1d91kf_xxz3_p92r0000gn/T/pip-install-y3069538/numba_6e6e423504184d79806b99ee58d7fab7/setup.py", line 413, in <module>
          metadata['ext_modules'] = get_ext_modules()
        File "/private/var/folders/hf/67v6_61j1d91kf_xxz3_p92r0000gn/T/pip-install-y3069538/numba_6e6e423504184d79806b99ee58d7fab7/setup.py", line 148, in get_ext_modules
          import numpy.distutils.misc_util as np_misc
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for numba
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py clean did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/hf/67v6_61j1d91kf_xxz3_p92r0000gn/T/pip-install-y3069538/numba_6e6e423504184d79806b99ee58d7fab7/setup.py", line 413, in <module>
          metadata['ext_modules'] = get_ext_modules()
        File "/private/var/folders/hf/67v6_61j1d91kf_xxz3_p92r0000gn/T/pip-install-y3069538/numba_6e6e423504184d79806b99ee58d7fab7/setup.py", line 148, in get_ext_modules
          import numpy.distutils.misc_util as np_misc
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for numba
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [26 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      /Users/jessicajacobs/anaconda3/envs/asoid/bin/python /private/var/folders/hf/67v6_61j1d91kf_xxz3_p92r0000gn/T/pip-install-y3069538/llvmlite_a807d3dcb820477b8a6ab3946bdf9b37/ffi/build.py
      LLVM version... Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/private/var/folders/hf/67v6_61j1d91kf_xxz3_p92r0000gn/T/pip-install-y3069538/llvmlite_a807d3dcb820477b8a6ab3946bdf9b37/ffi/build.py", line 105, in main_posix
          out = subprocess.check_output([llvm_config, '--version'])
        File "/Users/jessicajacobs/anaconda3/envs/asoid/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 415, in check_output
          return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
        File "/Users/jessicajacobs/anaconda3/envs/asoid/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 493, in run
          with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
        File "/Users/jessicajacobs/anaconda3/envs/asoid/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "/Users/jessicajacobs/anaconda3/envs/asoid/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1720, in _execute_child
          raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/path/to/llvm-config'
      
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/private/var/folders/hf/67v6_61j1d91kf_xxz3_p92r0000gn/T/pip-install-y3069538/llvmlite_a807d3dcb820477b8a6ab3946bdf9b37/ffi/build.py", line 191, in <module>
          main()
        File "/private/var/folders/hf/67v6_61j1d91kf_xxz3_p92r0000gn/T/pip-install-y3069538/llvmlite_a807d3dcb820477b8a6ab3946bdf9b37/ffi/build.py", line 185, in main
          main_posix('osx', '.dylib')
        File "/private/var/folders/hf/67v6_61j1d91kf_xxz3_p92r0000gn/T/pip-install-y3069538/llvmlite_a807d3dcb820477b8a6ab3946bdf9b37/ffi/build.py", line 107, in main_posix
          raise RuntimeError("%s failed executing, please point LLVM_CONFIG "
      RuntimeError: /path/to/llvm-config failed executing, please point LLVM_CONFIG to the path for llvm-config
      error: command '/Users/jessicajacobs/anaconda3/envs/asoid/bin/python' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for llvmlite
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numba, llvmlite, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

I'v consulted chatGPT which gave me various troubleshooting steps, which did not work. I made sure that numpy and llvm are installed, both in the base environment and in the conda environment I'm trying to create.

I'm not very experienced with python, conda, or working from the terminal. I mainly have used MATLAB in the past.

Comment: did you try installing numpy?

Comment: @JonSG, yes I did.

Comment: What command did you issue to get this error report? I am currently wondering if you are relying on the default Mac install of Python, and if it might be stuck on version 2.7 (which is very old).

Comment: After cloning the repository from GitHub I used the command "conda env create --file asoid.yml"... the command worked but stopped working and threw the above errors. 
I installed Python before starting this process and am using version 3.12.

Comment: @merv - the command you suggested worked! thank you so much!

Comment: Converted to answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Try Emulation

The issue here is probably that some of the older versions of packages - what they restrict to in the `requirements.txt` - cannot compile on Apple Silicon. If Pip assesses the architecture based on the Python architecture, then you might be able to get things working with emulation. That is, it might be worth trying

```
CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 conda env create --file asoid.yml
```

If that works, I'd be sure to permanently set that environment to be **osx-64**-only, i.e.,

```bash
conda activate asoid
conda config --env --set subdir osx-64
```

### Additional Notes

Note that this question is really about Pip, rather than Conda. The repository only uses Conda for providing Python + Pip, and Pip does everything else and is where the failure happens. However, telling Conda to install a non-ARM version of Python is the suggested workaround.

Were this me, I would play around with loosening some of the version constraints in the `requirements.txt` and edit the YAML file to install everything possible from Conda Forge rather than Pip. For me, native builds will always be preferable, and using Conda Forge's precompiled packages reduces unnecessary compilation.